# Is this site the proper SE site to ask questions about software dev processes?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have a few questions about the Agile process but not sure which SE is best suited for it. Is this the right site for it?

The current question(s) that I have:

- Is there an Agile term for when there is a stakeholder that acts as a bottleneck by jumping in only occasionally to trump decisions made collectively by the team? (ie, upper management who never partake in the process, but will occasionally review work and decide they don't like it)? I'm familiar with Pig and Chickens. Would this simply be a 'type of chicken'?
- Is there any technique to deal with said type of person?

Comment: Can you provide an example question? It always helps to have examples. Agile questions pertaining to software development usually are on topic here provided they are narrowly scoped and objective enough.

Comment: @WorldEngineer sample questions added!

Comment: consider checking existing questions in [tag:agile] to see what kind tends to be received well (there even be a prior question [similar to one you plan to ask](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/96089/31260))

Comment: "Bad Micromanager" ?

Comment: @gnat that question is different, but definitely in the same ballpark. Sounds like this question might fly here. I'll post it!

Answer (score 3):

Such a question is on-topic here at programmers.SE and it could also fit well on [Project Management.SE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/).

On programmers, the answers are likely to be more focussed on what you can do as a team member, while om Project Management, the answers might be more towards the role of a Product Owner/Scrum Master/manager.